# Netezza string comparison (spaces and without spaces)

Tags: string, netezza

Why does

```
select 'xyz' = 'xyz  '
```

return True in Netezza (7.2)? I am trying to build a comparison logic that considers a string with spaces to be different from a string without spaces but it does not work because of this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is according to ANSI SQL-92 predicate comparison rules. Strings must be padded to the same length with spaces prior to comparison.

If you want to avoid this behavior you can use "LIKE" instead of "=", or add a length() check to the "=" comparison.

```
select 'match' where 'xyz' = 'xyz ';
 ?COLUMN? 
----------
 match
(1 row)

select 'match' where 'xyz' like 'xyz ';
 ?COLUMN? 
----------
(0 rows)

select 'match' where 'xyz' = 'xyz ' and ( length('xyz') = length('xyz '));
 ?COLUMN? 
----------
(0 rows)
```